# How to 'create temp table as select' in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

Is there any way to create a temp table from a select statement in Slick without using a plain sql query?   I looked through the docs and was unable to find how to create a temp table, so I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is not supported yet. Slick's github shows it as an open issue:

https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/799