# How to run multiple plain sql queries in a single transaction in slick?

Tags: sql-server, scala, jdbc, playframework, slick

I have a Play/Slick application where I need to run multiple plain sql queries in a single transaction retrieving result of the last query like so:

```
val id: Future[Int] = db.run {
    sql"""
        DECLARE @T TABLE (id INTEGER)
        INSERT INTO Foo (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @T VALUES ('bar')
        SELECT id FROM @T
    """.as[Int].head
}
```

The problem with the above is that it always returns `1` which is a result of the top query that declares a temporary table. How do I get the result of the last query instead? Database in question is MS SQL Server. Play 2.5.4, Slick 3.1.1.

Comment: Split them to separate actions and do a for comprehension? And then add `.transactionally`?

Comment: @insan-e I was trying something like that, but couldn't work out the syntax, there's just no examples for that at all.

Comment: Yeah, the docs say almost 2 sentences about query composition...

Answer (score 14):

One of the most important features of Slick `Action`s is that they are composable, similar to the Scala `Future`s. IMHO, the docs don't treat it as much as it should... Here's an example:

```
val createAction = sqlu"""DECLARE @T TABLE (id INTEGER)"""
val insertAction = sqlu"""INSERT INTO Foo (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @T VALUES ('bar')"""
val selectAction = sql"""SELECT id FROM @T""".as[Int].head

val composedAction = for {
  createRes <- createAction
  insertRes <- insertAction
  selectRes <- selectAction
} yield selectRes

val id = db.run(composedAction.transactionally) // Future[...]
```

You could replace the `for` comprehension with `flatMap`s and a `map` at the end if you find it easier.

There are also two handy helpers from Slick, namely `DBIO.seq` (runs queries in sequence and **discards** the result, returns `Unit`) and `DBIO.sequence` (the same but **preserves** the results of all individual actions).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying someting similar, but it doesn't like `selectAction` in for composition, so your example doesn't compile with error `Compilation error[value map is not a member of slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder]`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `as[Int].head` at the end of the third query, but now the error is different - `SQLServerException: Must declare the table variable "@T".`, obviously meaning that queries are executed in parallel, so the for construct will not work here, only flatMap might.

Comment: I think not, the for comprehension is just syntax sugar for flatMap and map. Probably, the problem is with how Slick handles temporary table creation and executes queries... I'm not an expert here, lol.. xD

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981529/how-to-create-temp-table-as-select-in-slick) says that it's not possible yet, at all..

Comment: I'm not so sure, because my example above works, meaning it creates temp table and everything without any errors, only retrieving the value of the last query is not working, whereas with `for` or `flatMap` approach I'm pretty sure those queries run in parallel, hence the sql error.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible, means I'm dead in the water... Appreciate all the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the DBIO.seq(). Since DBIO.seq return Unit the selectAction then follows by andThen().

```
val createAction = sqlu"""DECLARE @T TABLE (id INTEGER)"""
val insertAction = sqlu"""INSERT INTO Foo (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @T VALUES ('bar')"""
val selectAction = sql"""SELECT id FROM @T""".as[Int].head

val id = db.run(DBIO.seq(createAction, insertAction) andThen selectAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend existing answers, provided queries could be run as a single query by omiting `INTO clause`. Instead:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INTEGER)
INSERT INTO Foo (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @T VALUES ('bar')
SELECT id FROM @T
```

The following could be used:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES ('bar')
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=55cf0732296974b6f83e8877206cfd18)**